# How to call an external script from .gitconfig alias?

Tags: bash, git, windows-10

I have an alias inside my .gitconfig that is a bit too complex and cumbersome to be on a single line.

```
[alias]
   foo = !f() { foo="$BASH_VERSION"; echo $foo; someComplexLogic...; }; f"
```

Is there a way to call out of the foo alias to a external file like myFooAlias.sh, where I would define all the logic?

This is on Windows 10.

Comment: Windows 10 and you're writing it in Bash?

Comment: @Schwern It's .gitconfig, so I am limited to that.  Am I wrong?

Comment: It is treated as "a shell command". Not 100% sure what it will be on Windows. Try `echo $SHELL` within an alias.

Comment: @Schwern I did `echo $BASH_VERSION` and that returns a version.  So I am reasonably sure that bash is on the system.  I think these days Windows includes many *nix tools.

Comment: More likely it ships with Git for Windows, `echo $SHELL` should give you a path. Either way, shell type confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefixing the alias with `!` will execute the alias as a shell command. If you want to run an executable, simply prefix it with a `!`.

```
[alias]
   foo = !myFooAlias.whatever
```